# Optimizing a simple pinball solver

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, optimization, game-physics

I am trying to solve a programming challenge and have succeeded in doing so only partly; I need to optimize the solution - and that's where *you* come in. First, the parameters:

- You are given some line segments `int x1, y1, x2, y2`.
- You are given a starting point `int px, py = INT_MAX` for your ball.
- You are to simulate a ball "dropping" from `px, py` straight downward (lesser values of y)

  - When it intersects a line, it follows that line until its lower endpoint
  - When no more lines intersect, output `px`.

So, what I figured:

- Read lines into list of line tuples `int xtop, ytop, xbot, ybot`,
- Sort lines by `ybot`. This allows us to skip lines that the ball has passed,
- Track index `imin` such that `lines[i].ybot >= py` for all `i < imin`, then until no intersect is found:

  - Maximize the vertical intersect `yi = kx + m`,
  - Set `px, py = lines[i].{x, y}bot`.

The problem is that this time complexity ∈ θ(n<sup>2</sup>) - IOW, it sucks for big inputs.

One idea is to use something like a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), but then the question is if it wouldn't be very expensive to calculate which lines go into which so-called half-spaces.

Comment: The lines can't intersect, can they?

Comment: Just paint lines on an invisible context, and drop the ball. Then check the ball if it is on a pixel with lines' color(check the color of actual position of ball(also neighbours)), it is intersecting. O(1)

Comment: "It follows that line until its lower endpoint." And then does it begin falling straight down again? Or does it continue to follow the slop of the previous line? Something else?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, indeed they cannot intersect.

Comment: @JimMischel they drop straight down.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're interested in [point location in a planar subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Slab_decomposition). The slab decomposition method to which I've linked is one of the simpler options; in a nutshell, you extend vertical lines from each endpoint of a segment, making 2n + 1 vertical *slabs*. For each slab, you compute a binary tree that indicates, from top to bottom, which segments cross the slab. Then, to find where the ball hits, determine which slab it's in and then which segment it hits (if any); both operations are O(log n)-time.

To compute the binary trees in the first place, use a sweep-line algorithm. Start with an empty binary tree and process the endpoints in sorted order of x-coordinate. For the left endpoint, insert the segment into the tree. For the right, remove it from the tree. Assuming that segments don't cross, reordering within the tree is never needed. Naively, we have to copy the tree after each step, but an easy strategy to get the storage down to O(n log n) from O(n^2) is to use a purely functional red-black tree, obviating the need for copies.

The overall running time and space for this approach are O(n log n).